# One-To-Many Association REST API

Tags: rest

We have a bit ambiguity problem here with the API design, specially with one to many association.

**Scenario:**

> Student – Has many – Books (one to many)

How should the API look to assign books to `student`? Expected behaviour is to remove some from existing and add new to existing.

`[POST] /students/1234/books` -  Not Allowed (As books can be assigned to other users later. May be suitable for a support ticket and comment scenario)

`[PUT] /students/1234/books`  –  From a pragmatic REST API point of view, it is the modification of the collection than an entity inside the collection.

**Existing Student Books :** `[{id:1, name:’REST1’, author:’Satish’, year:2003}, {id:2, name:’REST2’, author:’Satish’ , year:2003}]`

**Modified Student Books :** `[{id:2, name:’REST2’, author:’Satish’ , year:2003}, {id:3, name:’REST3’, author:’Satish’ , year:2003}]` – one removed and one new added.

Now this functionality could have been best achieved by only sending the list of book ids as shown below. But that would more be an action than resource oriented. On the other side sending the list of book objects for mapping would be quite heavy for mobile clients looks at the bandwidth available.

**Request Payload :** `[1, 2, 4]`

Is there a practice adapted in industry for such problems?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually the books themselves are also resources, so you should represent them. Although URLs are not important, but I might image something like this:

```
*/book/1
*/book/2
...
```

Basically if you have any "IDs" in any of the representations, it's almost a safe bet that those should be resources themselves.

From there you might decide to represent the relations to books too as separate resources. I assume it's an 'ownership' relation, although that's not entirely clear from your description. So students would have:

```
*/student/1234/ownedbook/111
*/student/1234/ownedbook/112
...
```

There might be an aggregate resource that supports POSTing a new book URL to own, GET to get a full list of owned books, and PUT to modify owned books in one go. Of course DELETEing one of the ownership links above would delete *only* the ownership of the book and not the book itself.

The representation of an ownership could be a single URL to the book itself, does not even have to be a json thing. The aggregate representation of ownerships is a simple list of URLs.

If you want to get fancy, you can decide to use [ATOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) to maintain the list of ownerships, that allows you to include additional information (not just the URL), so you have an easier time displaying (since you don't have to pull each book to find out the title, author, etc. to display).

Point is, represent everything "important" as a resource and they should refer to eachother by URL, not by ID. You have at least 3 important things: books, students, ownership relation. Everything else, like how the URLs look, whether it's json or xml, is not that important.